# Android getIntent() not returning expected Intent when launched from history

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, nfc, android-lifecycle

I have a problem with Activity lifecycle and NFC:

I have a MainActivity with the AndroidManifest.xml entry:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
    android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/androidbeam" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/nfctag" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
        android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
</activity>
```

where `launchMode="singleTask"` is used for NFC to prevent multiple MainActivity instances.

In MainActivity I have the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Timber.d("onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Timber.d("OnNewIntent");
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent){
         String action = intent.getAction();
            String intent_type = intent.getType();
            Timber.d("Intent action:" + action + "\n " + "Intent type:" + intent_type);
          if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action) || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
                // Handle data from intent.getParcelableExtra()
                Timber.d("onNFCDataReaded");

          }
          // and implementing creating of activity here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Timber.d("onResume");
        enableNFCDispatch(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Timber.d("onPause");
        super.onPause();
        disableNFCDispatch();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {  
        super.onDestroy();
        Timber.d("OnDestroy"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() { 
        super.onBackPressed();
        Timber.d("OnBackPressed");
    }

}
```

Everything works as expected, except for one use case:

When I am opening the application first with Android Beam or an NFC tag, `onCreate()` is called and it passes `getIntent()` to `handleIntent()` with the data received from another phone or an NFC tag. This works fine.

But after that, when I

1. click onBackPressed button inside MainActivity (i.e. exiting the application), and
2. then hold the Home button and in the overview screen select my application,

my application is opened again and `onCreate()` is called again. However, `getIntent()` returns the **old** intent with **same data** (intent.getAction(), intent.getParcelableExtra()) as I got with Android Beam or NFC tag!

I don't understand why! I expect to receive a new intent; the same as if the app is created when I click the application icon.

Can somebody help me with this?

Here is my MainActivity lifecycle:

```
MainActivity: onCreate
MainActivity: handleIntent
MainActivity:  Intent action: android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED 
               Intent type: application/androidbeam
MainActivity: onNFCDataReaded
MainActivity: OnResume  
MainActivity: OnBackPressed
MainActivity: onPause
MainActivity: OnDestroy

//After that, I am holding Home Button and selecting my application from
//OverViewScreen, and getting next Log:

MainActivity: onCreate
MainActivity: handleIntent
MainActivity: Intent action:android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED  
              Intent type:application/androidbeam      
             - // I do not expect it here !!!!! 
MainActivity: onNFCDataReaded      
MainActivity: OnResume
```

Comment: Well, it is expected behaviour...

Comment: @Selvin But how can I prevent getting the same intent inside onCreate() after opening application from OverView Screen ? I am not opening application by NFC interaction again, just reopening my Activity, so I do not have to handle that intent again

Comment: What about saving last Intent in onSaveInstanceState? then in onCreate you have to check if saveInstance is not null, obtain the intent and use it ... also there is a method `setIntent` which in most cases should be called inside `onNewIntent`

Comment: @Selvin Thanks for your help, but probably you did not understand correctly my problem, please check my Edit 1. OnNewIntent is not event called when I am starting my application by NFC, but it's called when I have opened application by it's icon, and after that did NFC interaction.

Comment: ok i see it now, it's not about onNewIntent ... Make a different activity with `noHistory="true"` for `NDEF_DISCOVERED` actions  ... so if app would be called with this action then it would not be in history(and cannot back to it from recent) ... but if would be called from lanucher it would possible ... edit: you may also use the same activity but use two `<activity-alias>` ... first for action MAIN  and second for both NDEF(this one with noHistory)

Comment: @Selvin I am not sure about idea to create another Activity with `noHistory="true"`, because I will need to pass parameters to MainActivity anyway, and after I click back from MainActivity and will try to reopen Application, I probably will have same situation as it is right now. But idea with `<activity-alias>` sounds nice, but I did not work with `<activity-alias>` yet....I have to read about it little bit... Or maybe can you show me how do you see my `AndroidManifest.xml` with `<activity-alias>` ? I'll try to do it myself anyway. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136559/discussion-between-andriy-antoniv-and-selvin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior. When you bring your activity to the background and later open the activity again from history (long-press home key), Android will recreate the previous activity stack and the activity will be launched with the same parameters as it was opened before. I.e. if it was launched with intent NDEF_DISCOVERED, it will, again, receive that intent.

However, you can easily detect if the activity was launched with the original intent or if it was launched from history. In the latter case, Android adds the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY` to the intent. Consequently, you can test for this flag in your `handleIntent()` method:

```
if ((intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) == 0) {
     if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()) ||
         NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like that's work for me! Thanks, you saved my day :)

Comment: and this `(intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) == 0` is always true, so I can't determine if it was started from startActivity with intent or from history stack with the same old intent